# AWS Amplify ISR generating pages in background

Tags: deployment, next.js, server-side-rendering, aws-amplify, ssg

I have a nextjs application that contains some pages that are using ISR and they update their data using some API calls when they are generated. This app is deployed on AWS Amplify. So when the deployment occurs it shows the pages generated and the ISR for each page as 86400 seconds.

Now the problem is that even though the revalidate time is of 24 hours these pages are getting generated every 30 seconds as I can see the server is getting requests of the APIs (integrated on these pages) every 30 seconds in the same series continuously in a loop which should have been once in every 24 hours.

So I want to know if there is some issue with amplify configuration or build settings of next that is causing this as I couldn't find anything related anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that lambda functions from earlier deployments were still running in backgrounds and generating pages. Aws needs to fix this from their side.

I deleted the app and created a new one in amplify console. As the build of the new app had different revalidate timing so it stopped regenerating.

Comment: so AWS perfectly honours revalidate timing?

Comment: Yes, at first, but if you update it then it revalidates for your earlier committed time as well as for new one.